# Does apollo local state update subscriber when data that is not being used is updated

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-link-state

Per the example in [the doc of apollo-link-state](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state.html#direct-writes), it states that

> Once you call client.writeData, the query result on the render prop function will automatically update

Let's say we keep two variables `foo` and `bar` in apollo local cache.
`ComponentFoo` is wrapped by Apollo `Query` that query `foo @client`.

Then there is somewhere in the app call `client.writeData({ data: bar: 'something' })`, will `ComponentFoo` render get triggered (via props change)?

Or is it triggered only when someone call `client.writeData({ data: foo: 'something' })` to update foo?

Answer (score 0):

`ComponentFoo` will be be updated only when `foo` is updated because only `foo` is defined within the `Query`.